# Error about deprecated Puppet MySQL keeps showing up

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

This is my manifest:

```
 class capstone() {
  include apache
  include mysql
  class {'apache::vhost':
    port    => 80,
    docroot => '/var/www/wordpress',
  }
  include 'apache::mod::php'
  class {'mysql::server' :
    root_password      => 'foo',
    override_options => {
        'mysqld'   => { 'max_connections' => '1024' },
    }
  }
  class {'mysql::bindings' :
    php_enable => true
  }
}
```

I wrote this in modules/capstone/manifests/init.pp

Inside modules, I have `stdlib`, `apache`, `concat`, `capstone`, `mysql`, `wordpress` which are all downloaded except `capstone`.

My error is:

```
Error: ERROR:  This class has been deprecated and the functionality moved
    into mysql::server.  If you run mysql::server without correctly calling
    mysql:: server with the new override_options hash syntax you will revert
    your MySQL to the stock settings.  Do not proceed without removing this
    class and using mysql::server correctly.

    If you are brave you may set attempt_compatibility_mode in this class which
    attempts to automap the previous settings to appropriate calls to
    mysql::server at /root/radiant/modules/mysql/manifests/init.pp:89 on node kim.puppetlabs.vm
Error: ERROR:  This class has been deprecated and the functionality moved
    into mysql::server.  If you run mysql::server without correctly calling
    mysql:: server with the new override_options hash syntax you will revert
    your MySQL to the stock settings.  Do not proceed without removing this
    class and using mysql::server correctly.

    If you are brave you may set attempt_compatibility_mode in this class w
```

I have googled around and have followed the suggestions in other links but I still get the same error. Not sure where I have done wrong.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1) do not include mysql

2) did not state the vhosts name correctly

This is the working manifest:

```
  class capstone() {
  include apache
  include apache::mod::php

  apache::vhost { 'wordpress.example.com':
    port    => 80,
    docroot => '/var/www/wordpress',
  }

  class {'mysql::server' :
    root_password      => 'foo',
    override_options => {
        'mysqld'   => { 'max_connections' => '1024' },
    }
  }
  class {'mysql::bindings' :
    php_enable => true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I also had "include mysql" in my setup from using an old version of the module, and it was causing the same breakage as this question once I updated. Unfortunate that the module repo README didn't help with this.